# Allylic Radicals Bromination Mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

For (a) (iii), how do you get the second product listed in the answers manual? I just can't visualize it.
[image] [image]

What about (c) (i), why are there three resonance structures? If a hydrogen is taken away from a specific carbon of the initial molecule to have a radical, there is no way you can have three resonance structures. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The barrier to rotation in the allyl radical is low (~[15-16 kcal/m](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00405a032http://)) and it can undergo cis-trans isomerization.

[image]

As to question (c)(i), you're right, there are only two resonance structures.

[image]

What you show above with three resonance structures is the [trimethylenemethane diradical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylenemethane), isobutene with 2 allylic hydrogens removed.

Comment: ron, what are the dotted lines? Why is there a positive charge?

Comment: the delocalized allyl radical, a shorthand way of drawing the 2 resonance structures; no positive charge, it is a radical, so just 1 unpaired electron.

Comment: The symbol that might look like a plus sign is just how my drawing software draws a radical.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know this barrier to rotation was so easy. It seems that Solomons' textbook does not discuss this. :O Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ron, I have encountered a problem with (c). I'm editing the question. Could you solve my concern?

Comment: @yolo123  I'll edit my answer to cover this.