# Do free radicals re-arrange?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, radicals

For example reaction of **but-1-ene** in the presence of $\ce{Br2}$ and light should give **1-bromobut-2-ene** which is thermodynamically more stable than  **3-bromobut-1-ene** on the basis of number of alpha hydrogen.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @MaxW You can edit incorrect naming, you know. Also the correct nomenclature is but-1-ene, not 1-butene.

Comment: @user22443, what actually is your *question?*

Comment: the reaction comes under substitution by free radical mechanism , in presence of peroxide + light or just light , halogens show this reaction in particular, with the exception of fluorine and iodine( since backward reaction is favorable). I chose bromine since it is more selective( w.r.t this reaction). Reaction is initiated by homolysis of halogen. halogen free radical takes away hydrogen of  sp3 carbon. after which the free radical substrate takes halogen free radical . Reaction is similar to that by N-bromo succinamide which takes place in allylic system.

Comment: @Jan My teacher says that free radical intermediates do not rearrange like carbocations do, but the reaction i mentioned above involves free radical rearrangement as it leads to a more stable product as compared to the product obtained by no re arrangemnt

Comment: LOL - I wonder if the nomenclature changed. I surely think it was 1-butene when I took organic chem.

Comment: If I am not wrong, for this reaction to be carried out, you have to keep the concentration of $\ce{Br2}$ extremely low to avoid forming the unwanted addition product. It's for that reason that NBS is often used: in combination with $\ce{HBr}$, it maintains a steady, but low, concentration of $\ce{Br.}$ *Anyway*, in carbocations, the mechanism of shifting is called a "hydride" shift: basically, the hydrogen is taking both of the electrons in the C-H bond together with it. This can't happen in radicals as it would result in a 9-electron carbon. I'm not sure if a hydrogen radical shift can occur.

Comment: It is a matter of timing. The "normal" reaction between a carbon double bond and Br2 would be to brominate both carbons. But if UV light breaks Br2 into 2 Br atoms (radicals) then the Br "plucks" a H from the hydrocarbon giving a free radical. The hydrocarbon free radical rearranges, then sometime later finds a Br2 molecule and forms Bromohydrocarbon and yielding another Br atom.

Comment: @MaxW since 1993, the IUPAC name is but-1-ene.

Comment: @ortho seal: Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement ;)

Comment: @user22443 Please add that relevant information *to the question* using the edit button.

Comment: @Jan Is that not a "normal" alkyl migration? Same as a hydride shift just that it's C-C instead of C-H. I mean alkyl migrations can certainly happen in carbocations too (Friedel-Crafts alkylation is the oft-cited example) but I ran out of space in that comment ._.

Comment: @Loong - I took organic chem in the summer of 1971 so you made me feel a bit better. I haven't done any chemistry in 20 years.

Comment: @orthocresol yes a hydride shift is not possible but is this kind of double bond shift allowed?

Comment: @user22443 Oh, you're right. I just realised it's not about migration of hydrogen... just the double bond shifting. Sorry.. And yes, of course it is possible. http://i.imgur.com/5iuQbxM.png See this question. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16826/alllylic-bromination-of-1-butene